# Codeception's Autoload class doesn't autoload

Tags: php, testing, namespaces, autoload, codeception

I'm trying to autoload a bunch of helpers into a test suite. The helpers are located in a folder outside of the test suite in the hopes that I can reuse them across multiple projects if needed.

This is pretty much what I have:

```
- helpers
    - TestHelper.php
- tests
    - _data
    - _output
    - _support
        - _generated
        - Helper
            - Integration.php
        - IntegrationTester.php
    - integration
    - bootstrap.php
    - integration.suite.yml
- vendor
- codeception.yml
```

This is the bootstrap file

```
// bootstrap.php

<?php

\Codeception\Util\Autoload::addNamespace( "awesome\helpers", __DIR__ . "../helpers" );
```

This is the global config file:

```
// codeception.yml

bootstrap: bootstrap.php
namespace: main
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

This is the integration suite's config file:

```
// integration.suite.yml

actor: IntegrationTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \awesome\helpers\TestHelper
        - \main\Helper\Integration
```

This is the TestHelper:

```
<?php

namespace awesome\helpers;

class TestHelper extends \Codeception\Module{

   public function sayHello() {
      return "Hello"; 
   }

}
```

As soon as I do `codecept run`, I get the following error:

> Module \awesome\helpers\TestHelper could not be found and loaded

I'm not posting any tests because it's irrelevant, the error is raised before any test is performed as it's a config issue.

From what I understand, the global config file should run the bootstrap file before the tests are run, and the Autoload class in the bootstrap file should load the helpers in the `awesome\helpers` namespace, but that's clearly not happening. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just use composer autoloader instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you made a classical mistake and missed `/` before `..` so you set the path to `tests../helpers`.

Change

```
\Codeception\Util\Autoload::addNamespace( "awesome\helpers", __DIR__ . "../helpers" );
```

to

```
\Codeception\Util\Autoload::addNamespace( "awesome\helpers", __DIR__ . "/../helpers" );
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you.